# how to check when I click my crossIcon button the pop closes?

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

**const CrossIcon = ({ className, onClick, background, isHidden=false, }) => {
if(isHidden) return null
return 



}**

this i what i did.....

it('to see crossIcon is closed after i click',async ()=>{

```
const props = {className : "", background :""} ;
   render(<CrossIcon {...props} />)

   expect(screen.getByTestId('bar-1')).toBeInTheDocument();
   expect(screen.getByTestId('bar-2')).toBeInTheDocument()
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('bar-1'));
  
  expect(screen.queryByTestId('bar-1')).toBeNull()
```

})

Comment: What happens when onClick function is called? Do you remove the crossIcon from the DOM ?

Comment: it closes the pop-up window

Comment: Then you just add test cases for popup to be present in the DOM  before you click on close, and not to be present in the DOM after you click on the close button.

Comment: Could you please provide the full code for the component under test?